# How to query for data in streaming buffer ONLY in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a table partitioned by day in BigQuery, which is updated by streaming inserts.

The [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) says that: "when streaming to a partitioned table, data in the streaming buffer has a NULL value for the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo column"

But if I query for `select count(*) from table where _PARTITIONTIME is NULL` it always returns 0, even though `bq show` tells me that there are a lot of rows in the streaming buffer.

Does this mean that the pseudo column is not present at all for rows in streaming buffer? In any case, how can I query for the data ONLY in the streaming buffer without it becoming a full table scan?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the practical use case for this? i don't think you can query/read streaming buffer, but if you explain why you think you need to be able to read it  - we might figure out how to make it

Comment: I have a streaming job that keeps updating a table in BigQuery. I have a downstream job that triggers every 15 mins and aggregates the data for the day so far - so it needs to query something equivalen to `where _PARTITIONTIME = today OR data_in_streaming_buffer`. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Data in the streaming buffer has a `NULL` value for the `_PARTITIONTIME` column.

```
SELECT
  fields
FROM
  `dataset.partitioned_table_name`
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME IS NULL
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#copying_to_partitioned_tables

Comment: What if I need to compute an aggregation on data in the buffer? What should I do? It seems that I cant even do a filter like  "where value > =200". Any suggestions on what to do? Should I use any other product instead?

Comment: Answering my own question - Created a "With"-statement first with the query and then filtered.

Comment: This only works for ingestion-time partitioned tables. Otherwise the column `_PARTITIONTIME` doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 3):

When you stream data to BQ you usually have the "warming-up" period and that's the time it takes for the streamed data to become available for operations such as querying, copying and exporting.

The doc states in the end that after a period of up to 90 mins the pseudo-column `_PARTITIONTIME` receives a non-null value, which means your streamed data is fully ready for any type of operation you want to run on the data (being able to run queries usually takes a few seconds).

That means that you don't [query partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables) looking for when this field is null but instead, you do like so:

```
SELECT
  fields
FROM
  `dataset.partitioned_table_name`
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-01-20')
```

In this example, you would be querying only data streamed in the dates partition Jan/20 (which avoids a full table scan).

You can also select for a range of dates, you would just have to change the `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-01-20') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-01-22')
```

Which would query for 2 days in your table.

Comment: Using `WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP(some_day)` does not query the streaming buffer - if I query for the latest record using a time field in the schema, the result of full table scan is more than an hour newer than the one with a where partitiontime clause

Comment: Do you have a link that points to the docs where the 90 mins period is mentioned?

Comment: Hi @lv10, here it goes: [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability). I have the impression that my answer is not quite correct now that I read it again. Still, it can take up to 90 mins for copy and export operations to be fully ready for streamed data.