# Query Streaming Data Using --time_partitioning_field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am currently exploring how to query only the streaming buffer data in tables at regular intervals for generating a performance report at near real-time and found the following StackOverflow link:

[How to query for data in streaming buffer ONLY in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864257/how-to-query-for-data-in-streaming-buffer-only-in-bigquery)

However, the current type of partition is implemented using `--time_partitioning_field`

Using the following query forces to query all data from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM `<project>.<data-set>.<time-partitioned-streaming-table>`
where <time-partitioning-field> is null
```

[image]

The query doesn't show any difference as ideally the peak streaming buffer is @ ~60MB per hour

Is there a way to query only the streaming data with this type of partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work (but it is legacy SQL)

```
#standardSQL
 CREATE TABLE test.newtable (transaction_id INT64, transaction_date DATE)
 PARTITION BY transaction_date
 OPTIONS(
   partition_expiration_days=3,
   description="a table partitioned by transaction_date"
 )

#legacySQL
select * from [test.newtable$__UNPARTITIONED__]
```

Comment: Partition by time partitioning field support only #standardSQL.. `Error: Querying tables partitioned on a field is not supported in Legacy SQL`

Comment: Logan: what query you run - when you got this error?

Comment: I added creation statement for table with time-partitioned field to my answer. This query does not produced any errors.

Comment: it works .. I got that error for the regular select <*> from table query.. thought it is not supporting legacy sql anymore.. thanks :-)

Comment: Is there a way to get the streaming buffer data using standard sql as well?

Comment: I doubt it is exists for standard - legacy sql is more "low" level language that allow to access some features not available in standard SQL (and probably will never be available)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to query streaming buffer data for [partioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#comparing_partitioning_options) because once a specific `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` has been defined, data is ["streamed directly to the partition"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#ingestion-time_partitioned_tables_95_unpartitioned_partition).

Checking the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#the_95partitiondate_pseudo_column) you can also find the solution for ingestion-time partitioned tables mentioned in the link you posted.