# How do I query the streaming buffer in BigQuery if the _PARTITIONTIME field isn't available with Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a partitioned BigQuery table that's partitioned on a custom field (`event_timestamp`).  This was due to needing to import historical data while still keeping things partitioned and query costs under control.

This means the table doesn't have a `_PARTITIONTIME` field, and we can't do queries `WHERE _PARTITIONTIME IS NULL` to view recently sent records sitting in the streaming buffer.

So is there a trick to being able to query the streaming buffer even if you're using a custom field for partitioning?

**Edit**  We're using Standard SQL, not Legacy SQL, sorry for not being explicit about that previously.

Comment: can you say more about your goal when querying just for the data existing in the buffer?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Primarily it's to test/verify that functions are working as expected and writing/capturing the expected data.  The delays with flushing make this lack of visibility a regular stumbling block.  Typically when you don't get the results back you expect, you assume it's your code - in this case it's actually working, but things are hidden in the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though querying tables with time partitioning field supports only via standard SQL, I believe Legacy SQL is still supported to query the streaming inserts into the table

```
#legacySQL
select * from [<project-name>:<data-set>.<table>$__UNPARTITIONED__]
```

Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

[Query Streaming Data Using --time_partitioning_field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797189/query-streaming-data-using-time-partitioning-field)

Comment: Hey @Logan thanks for the link - I'm updating my question to specify Standard SQL, because otherwise your answer would be spot-on.  I apologize for not being more specific (and in fact maybe there is no Standard SQL method available)

Comment: Marking this as the answer, as I don't think there's a solution under Standard SQL

Comment: We're now almost two years later; I can't believe there's still no solution to do this in Standard SQL! However, as of yet this is the only way I've found that allows me to query the streaming buffer of a table partitioned on a field. Thanks!