# Querying buffer/unpartitioned data using standard sql in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

(I am guessing based on [How do I query the streaming buffer in BigQuery if the _PARTITIONTIME field isn't available with Standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050669/how-do-i-query-the-streaming-buffer-in-bigquery-if-the-partitiontime-field-isn)  that my question has no simple solution, so I will "enhance" it)

---

I stream my data into Bigquery's partitioned and clustered table using a timestamp field (not an ingestion time partition).
I want to have a view that always look into the last hour data, what already in the table, plus what still in the buffer.
Since this table is not an ingestion time partitioned table, there is no pseudo column _PARTITIONTIME/DATE, so I can't use it in order to get the buffer data.
The only way I've found is by using legacy SQL:     `SELECT * FROM [dataset.streaming_data$__UNPARTITIONED__]`
This is not good enough for me, since even if I save this as a view, I can't refer to a legacy SQL view from a standard SQL query.
Any idea how I can achieve this ?

---

Another idea I am thinking of - bigquery can have an external data source (using `EXTERNAL_QUERY`), which I can query using standard SQL.
A solution might be some "temporary" table on a separate database (such as PostgreSQL Cloud SQL) which will only have 1 hour of data, and won't have bigquery's buffer mechanism.
I think this is a bad solution, but I guess it might work...
What do you think ?

Comment: The query results should already include anything in the buffer - did you test for this?

Comment: Wow ! Thanks ! Amazing - I am so bothered in not executing queries without "partition", that I was staying "in the loop" of what I already know, without checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@Felipe Hoffae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132438/felipe-hoffa) I just found out I need to do nothing :-)
Buffered data is already available in any SQL query if the WHERE clause includes the data in it...